# on the Home page, Id like to get notifications of changes to subsites.. is this possible

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We have a home page with 20+ subsites. At the minute when someone changes a sub-site, we are not notified of the Change.

Is it possible for all changes to be highlighted on the home page? Allowing all users to quickly see what's new or happening within the company?

Currently, the home page is updated regularly with company info, the subsites would be related to different areas of the company - e.g. Sales, Finance, would all update their own subsite with news for that area,

We use SharePoint Foundation Server 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar request from my users in a site collection. We ended up using the Content Query Web Party which looks up for SharePoint's Items and sorts them by Recently Changed. This works well for page changes, document changes, list item changes and newly added site content additions.

It doesn't exactly generate a *notify*, but in any event slightly active site collection each notification would end up to generate a reasonably huge mass of notifications.

It is also to be noted, that CQWP is dependent on the incremental search crawl, so by default it will be updated once an hour.